# Java Collections

Tags: java, hashmap

I am adding the following to the HashMap collection after each row in the UI form

Declaration

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Code snippet

```
    valSetOne.add("BMW");
    valSetOne.add("Audi");
    map.put("A1", valSetOne);
```

When I am in the second row in UI, I would like to check the above combination
exist in the HashMap collection.

How can I check for the combination of values in each row?

Comment: Use the `containsValue()` method?

Comment: @Kayaman Does contains check for entire row?

Comment: You don't have rows. You have a `Map` of `Lists`. If you call `containsValue(myList)`, it will check if `myList` is already contained within the values.

Comment: Consider looking at https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html - it might simplify your list-in-map processing considerably and provide you with some helpful utility methods.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski Thanks for the suggestion. We do have a restriction in using third party libraries and due to this we wouldn't be able to external JAR files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need performance with respect to checking if a value exists and dont care about the order in each row, you can use Set interface and use a HashSet instead of List

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

Set<String> valSetOne = new HashSet<String>();
```

To check, use

```
Set<String> set= map.get("A1");//returns null if key does not exists(you also use containsKey() to check if key exists)
set.contains("value")
```

If you dont need performance, u can just use

```
List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list = map.get("A1");//returns null if key does not exists(you also use containsKey() to check if key exists )
list .contains("value") to check if it exists
```

Comment: You need to check for both the values separately either in list or in a set. but set gives better performance if u just want to check whether it exists or not and dont care about the order

Comment: Oh yes I got your point, for A1 key, the combination of Orange and Apple exists or not correct?

Comment: yes. you need to run a loop to check whether orange as well as apple exists or not for A1

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you'd like to check for existence, there are two Map methods:
`containsKey` and `contiansValue`.

need to check is key `A1` there? -> use `containsKey`

need to check is there a list with `Orange` and `Apple` use -> `containsValue`

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated.